# Facing issues while installing apcu_bc package on PHP 8

Tags: php, php-8, apcu

Facing below errors while installing package  `pecl install apcu_bc`  on PHP 8

```
In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/apcu_bc/php_apc.c:35:
/usr/local/include/php/ext/apcu/apc_arginfo.h:4:3: error: #error Not supported on PHP >= 8.0
 # error Not supported on PHP >= 8.0
   ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/php/main/php.h:35,
                 from /tmp/pear/temp/apcu_bc/php_apc.c:23:
/usr/local/include/php/Zend/zend_API.h:85:69: error: 'zif_apcu_store' undeclared here (not in a function); did you mean 'zif_apc_dec'?
 #define ZEND_FALIAS(name, alias, arg_info)   ZEND_RAW_FENTRY(#name, zif_##alias, arg_info, 0)
                                                                     ^~~~
/usr/local/include/php/Zend/zend_API.h:77:74: note: in definition of macro 'ZEND_RAW_FENTRY'
 #define ZEND_RAW_FENTRY(zend_name, name, arg_info, flags)   { zend_name, name, arg_info, (uint32_t) (sizeof(arg_info)/sizeof(struct _zend_internal_arg_info)-1), flags },
                                                                          ^~~~
/usr/local/include/php/main/php.h:387:21: note: in expansion of macro 'ZEND_FALIAS'
 #define PHP_FALIAS  ZEND_FALIAS
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/pear/temp/apcu_bc/php_apc.c:173:2: note: in expansion of macro 'PHP_FALIAS'
  PHP_FALIAS(apc_store,    apcu_store,    arginfo_apcu_store)
  ^~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/pear/temp/apcu_bc/php_apc.c:173:42: error: 'arginfo_apcu_store' undeclared here (not in a function)
  PHP_FALIAS(apc_store,    apcu_store,    arginfo_apcu_store)
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/php/Zend/zend_API.h:77:80: note: in definition of macro 'ZEND_RAW_FENTRY'
 #define ZEND_RAW_FENTRY(zend_name, name, arg_info, flags)   { zend_name, name, arg_info, (uint32_t) (sizeof(arg_info)/sizeof(struct _zend_internal_arg_info)-1), flags },
                                                                                ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/php/main/php.h:387:21: note: in expansion of macro 'ZEND_FALIAS'
 #define PHP_FALIAS  ZEND_FALIAS
```

Is apcu_bc package supported on PHP 8?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In addition to sung jack answer.

[php-apcu-bc is dropped in PHP 8](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/Transition/Php8.0) as there is no dependency on it.

But APCu is still in use. you can install it by using below commands

```
mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext/apcu && curl -fsSL        https://pecl.php.net/get/apcu | tar xvz -C "/usr/src/php/ext/apcu" --strip 1 && docker-php-ext-install apcu
```

OR

```
RUN pecl install APCu
   && docker-php-ext-enable apcu
    && echo "apc.enabled=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/apcu.ini \
    && echo "apc.enable_cli=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/apcu.ini \
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately....  according to the response from the maintainer.

```
some changes in APCu API make this component dead and unsupported for PHP 8
```

Issue link: https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu-bc/issues/34.